# How to add custom field to view-edit post type page

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I want to add a custom field at top of the custom post type list page.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance guys!
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What is this custom field for, are you wanting to view a custom field that's already been added to your CPT, sort by one that exists, bulk add custom postmeta, etc.?

Comment: @WebElaine
I need a custom field (checkbox). If is checked, it will send an ajax post request to the server. the checkbox will send some info specific for this post type.
So of course i need that the state of the field will be preserved in the DB.
thats why i need custom field